# SQL line break after X characters

Tags: sql, line, break

i'm trying to add an auto line break after a certain amount of characters in SQL
here is what the column looks like

[image: column]

i'm getting the user input in a form like this

```
<form action='xx.php' method="post">
<label  for="commentaire">Commentaire</label></br>
<input style="width:800px;" type="text" name="commentaire" id=""></br>
<input type='submit' name='com' value="Ajouter commentaire" /></br> 
</form>
```

and displaying the row in my code like this

```
echo "<div id=com>".
"$row['commentaire']".
"</div>";
```

The div com has a width of 500px and it sometimes overflow the div when the input is too long.

i've heard about

```
CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
```

but since i'm getting a single user input i don't know how and if it can work.

Comment: I would handle the comment transformation in php (or even javascript on client side) instead of SQL, it will be easier.

Comment: I think you want `<BR/>` since most browser will ignore carriage return line feed (CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))

Comment: It sounds like something that could (maybe even should) be solved with CSS, because it's only a display issue. And Hogan is right, except if it is inside a textarea.

Comment: it was indeed a css tricks, a simple `word-wrap: break-word;` did it, thanks man